# Vector transformation based on another vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors. The first one has the value that I want to study, the second one indicates the index where the value should be. Let's take an example, I have two vectors as follow:

```
a = c(1,2,2,1,2)
b = c(9,10)
```

I would like to transform vector a into a vector like this:

```
a = c(9,10,10,9,10)
```

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Simply `b[a]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Use subscripting:

```
a = c(1,2,2,1,2)
b = c(9,10)
b[a]
## [1]  9 10 10  9 10
```

**2)** Another approach is to turn it into a factor with `b` as its labels and then convert it back to numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.character(factor(a, levels = sort(unique(a)), labels = b)))
## [1]  9 10 10  9 10
```